# Should my farm account be in the local admins group?

Tags: permissions, service-account, managed-account

In my Review problems and solutions reports I have the following Security Warning:

[image: Security Warning]

Both of the offending services use my "farm" managed account (I named it SP_Farm on my domain, it's the one you have to enter during the SP configuration wizard when you're ready to set up the DBs).

Recently I went through a boot camp (got my MCTS: SharePoint 2010, Configuration cert) and as part of the course they told us that the farm account needed to be a local admin on the machine(s) where your SharePoint server(s) is(are) installed.

My question is:  How will it affect my server if I remove SP_Farm from the local administrators group on my server?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The farm account does not need to be a member of the local Administrator group.  For a farm it should be a domain user, when you run the configuration wizard it will be granted the required user rights, file permissions, registry permissions, DCOM permissions, and DB permissions.

When you do your initial Sync with UPS, you will need to add the farm account to the local admins on the machine doing the sync, but this only for the first sync, after which you can remove it from the admin group.

Technet guides to refer too:

[Plan for administrative and service accounts](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc263445.aspx#Subsection2)

[Plan Administrative tasks in least privileged environment](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh377944.aspx)

It should not affect your farm to remove it from the admin group, but after removing the permissions (and rebooting), you may want to have SP reset the security settings.  You can do this via Powershell so you don't have run the entire psconfig wizard.

```
Initialize-SPResourceSecurity
```

Comment: Agreed. But some times Third Party Backup software may require local admin privileges

Comment: Your third party backup software shouldn't be using the farm service account, but instead a dedicated service account that has been granted the appropriate permissions on the servers and in the farm.

Answer (score 1):

A great article that might help [Link](http://www.harbar.net/archive/2007/06/19/NO-Your-SharePoint-Farm-Account-does-NOT-need-local-admin.aspx)

Comment: Hi @Paul-akerlind please add some context on your external link to the question itself and *then* link to the answer. We like to keep the answers in-site, and external links tend to die! Please fix this. Thanx